# foreach loop in QT not working in this example?

Tags: c++, qt

I generally never get caught in looping. But looks like I am clueless here on the looping logic. When I put a break in the inner for loop, the values I get is always 0. However, when I remove break, I get the right values. What is wrong in my code?

```
void ContentCache::getAggregatorList()
{
    TLOG_FUNC_ENTER();
    ContentAggregator  *aggregator =  ContentAggregator::Instance();
    QList <ContentID>   aggContentList;
    /* Get the service list from the aggregator */
    aggregator->getContentList(CONTENT_TYPE_LIVE_SERVICE, aggContentList);
    QList<Attribute> attributeListOut;
    ContentID content;
    foreach( content, aggContentList )
    {
        TLOG_INFO("SJ..main loop");
        //if(content.source == TERRESTRIAL_BROADCAST_SOURCE )
        //  {
        doGetServiceAttributes(content,attributeListOut);
        unsigned int attributeIndex = 0;
        foreach( Attribute attr, attributeListOut)
        {
            TLOG_INFO("SJ..Inner loop");
            if(attr.name == "chanNum")
            {
                TLOG_INFO("SJ..The  attr channelNum is = "<<attr.value.toInt());
                if( attr.value.toUInt() == 999)
                {
                    TLOG_INFO("SJ..The changed attr channelNum is"<<attr.value.toUInt());
                    attr.name = "chanNum";
                    attr.value = 200;
                    attributeListOut.replace(attributeIndex,attr);
                    TLOG_INFO("SJ..The changed attr channelNum is"<<attr.value.toUInt());
                    m_cacheDB->terrestrialUpdateService(content,attributeListOut);
                }
                else
                {
                    TLOG_INFO("SJ..The unmodified attr channelNum is"<<attr.value.toUInt());
                }
                break;
            }
            attributeIndex++;
            //  }
        }
    }
    // getAttributeValues(ContentID id, QList<QString> value, QList<Attribute> &attributeListOut);
}*
```

Comment: Do you make a networking? If so, maybe you miss some responses while you are breaking?

Comment: which is the variable that you are tracking (ie: which gives you 0 with the `break` and "right values" without break)?

Comment: did you step through in a debugger?

Comment: I don't have a debugger, I can put only prints

Comment: Demand a debugger, or go on strike :D

Comment: solved - see my answer. It's quite a strange solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed clearing up the object - under pressure.Here is the silly solution to my silly problem. QList attributeListOut was not getting over-written, in fact it gets appended here. This was the problem. This should not be the case ideally. But, it all depends on how the operators are overloaded.

```
void ContentCache::getAggregatorList()
{
    TLOG_FUNC_ENTER();
    ContentAggregator  *aggregator =  ContentAggregator::Instance();
    QList <ContentID>   aggContentList;
    /* Get the service list from the aggregator */
    aggregator->getContentList(CONTENT_TYPE_LIVE_SERVICE, aggContentList);
    QList<Attribute> attributeListOut;
    ContentID content;
    foreach( content, aggContentList )
    {
        TLOG_INFO("SJ..main loop");
        //if(content.source == TERRESTRIAL_BROADCAST_SOURCE )
        //  {
        attributeListOut.clear();
        doGetServiceAttributes(content,attributeListOut);
        unsigned int attributeIndex = 0;
        foreach( Attribute attr, attributeListOut)
        {
            TLOG_INFO("SJ..Inner loop");
            if(attr.name == "chanNum")
            {
                TLOG_INFO("SJ..The  attr channelNum is = "<<attr.value.toInt());
                if( attr.value.toUInt() == 999)
                {
                    TLOG_INFO("SJ..The changed attr channelNum is"<<attr.value.toUInt());
                    attr.name = "chanNum";
                    attr.value = 200;
                    attributeListOut.replace(attributeIndex,attr);
                    TLOG_INFO("SJ..The changed attr channelNum is"<<attr.value.toUInt());
                    m_cacheDB->terrestrialUpdateService(content,attributeListOut);
                }
                else
                {
                    TLOG_INFO("SJ..The unmodified attr channelNum is"<<attr.value.toUInt());
                }
                break;
            }
            attributeIndex++;
            //  }
        }
    }
    // getAttributeValues(ContentID id, QList<QString> value, QList<Attribute> &attributeListOut);
}*
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the break, you're counting all  `Attribute`s.  With the break, you're only counting attributes up to the first one that has `attr.name == "chanNum"` which doesn't seem likely to be useful.  It's not entirely clear what you intended the `break` to do.

One way to help with such things is to pull out just the logic and try it in a simplified form.  For example (in C++11 form):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string string1{"BONGO"};
    std::string string2{"This is string2"};

    std::cout << "With the break\n";
    for ( auto ch : string1 )
    {
        unsigned int attributeIndex = 0;
        for( auto c: string2 )
        {
            if( c > 'a')
            {
                if( c > 'i')
                {
                    std::cout << ch << c << "+";
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << ch << c << "-";
                }
                break;
            }
            std::cout << ch << c << "@";
            attributeIndex++;
        }
        std::cout << attributeIndex << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "Without the break\n";
    for ( auto ch : string1 )
    {
        unsigned int attributeIndex = 0;
        for( auto c: string2 )
        {
            if( c > 'a')
            {
                if( c > 'i')
                {
                    std::cout << ch << c << "+";
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << ch << c << "-";
                }
                // no break
            }
            std::cout << ch << c << "@";
            attributeIndex++;
        }
        std::cout << attributeIndex << '\n';
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
With the break
BT@Bh-1
OT@Oh-1
NT@Nh-1
GT@Gh-1
OT@Oh-1
Without the break
BT@Bh-Bh@Bi-Bi@Bs+Bs@B @Bi-Bi@Bs+Bs@B @Bs+Bs@Bt+Bt@Br+Br@Bi-Bi@Bn+Bn@Bg-Bg@B2@15
OT@Oh-Oh@Oi-Oi@Os+Os@O @Oi-Oi@Os+Os@O @Os+Os@Ot+Ot@Or+Or@Oi-Oi@On+On@Og-Og@O2@15
NT@Nh-Nh@Ni-Ni@Ns+Ns@N @Ni-Ni@Ns+Ns@N @Ns+Ns@Nt+Nt@Nr+Nr@Ni-Ni@Nn+Nn@Ng-Ng@N2@15
GT@Gh-Gh@Gi-Gi@Gs+Gs@G @Gi-Gi@Gs+Gs@G @Gs+Gs@Gt+Gt@Gr+Gr@Gi-Gi@Gn+Gn@Gg-Gg@G2@15
OT@Oh-Oh@Oi-Oi@Os+Os@O @Oi-Oi@Os+Os@O @Os+Os@Ot+Ot@Or+Or@Oi-Oi@On+On@Og-Og@O2@15
```

Using techniques like this can help you work out the logic abstractly and then code with confidence in the real project.